# Why modal calling from ajax response is not closing?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working for a small project.In this project I have a modal which is called with ajax response after clicking.But the modal is not closing.Any ideas about how I can sove this bugs.Thanks in advance.

My demo code:

```html
<button class="open-modal">Open modal</button>
<div
  class="modal fade reactor_modal "
  id="modal"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="modalTitle"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
</div>
```

JS code

```js
$('.open-modal').click(function(post_id) {
  var $modal = $('.modal');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'get_react_user.php',
    type: get,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $($modal).modal("show");
      $($modal).html(data)
      console.log($modal);
    }
  })
})
$(document).on('click','.close-modal',function()
$('.modal').modal('hide')
})
```

PHP code

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Reactions</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <h1>Working</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this using Bootstrap?

Comment: This is not the problem, but FYI you don't need to use `$($modal)` - `$modal` is enough.  Any errors on the console?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this [ demo jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8u19pgrn/ ]

> you need to replace url https://picsum.photos/480/320 with your src

```js
$('.open-modal').click(function(post_id) {

  var $modal=  $('.modal');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/480/320',
  type:'get',
  dataType: 'HTML',
    cache: false, 
    beforeSend:function(){
        $('.modal-body').html('<h3>Please wait... Loading...</h3>')
    },
    success:function(data){    
            // set your respone in your modal-body
       let response = '<h1>this is just response temporary</h1>'
       // $('.modal-body').html(data) // uncomment to set your response & comment next code
       $('.modal-body').html(response)  // comment     
    }
  })  
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary open-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Open modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you change from OP's code?  Why do you think it will help?  This may be the answer, but adding an explanation would greatly increase the quality of your answer.  *Explain* your answer, so future visitors of all skill levels can learn from it.  [Code-only answers are considered low quality on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding class="btn btn-default" to the close button.
Also try looking at this URL example, hope that It will help.

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-close-bootstrap-modal

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```